# Missing .exe.config on program load, how do you recover?

Tags: c#, config

I have a program that stores various settings in the the `application.exe.conifg` file and when the program load, in the constructor I get these various settings into memory.

It turns out if you delete that config file, and run the application by directly starting the exe, not via the MS IDE, then the program will just crash.

I have yet to find a way how to recover properly from this error so that it doesn't crash, but just creates a new .exe.config file when one doesn't exist.

Has anyone had this issue and how do you resolve it?

Comment: Haha I never needed that config file only exe here and it works. Try decompiling your application and rebuilding it. It's a snap with .NET languages. I'd recommend the program `Dis#` works with minor edits and `Reflector from Red Gate` as a double checker.

Comment: Strange, it actually should not crash, but use the default values that are provided in the Settings class automatically maintained for your project...

Comment: Can you share your stacktrace?

Comment: Is it a good idea to modify the application.exe.config file at runtime? I would think it's not allowed in many environments. Settings should be saved in a settings file that is not in the program's .exe folder.

Comment: I agree with Thorsten, it should not crash but instead use the default values it was compiled with. Please show the code and the exception details of the crash, the likely problem is your default values cause the crash (or you are not using a default value through `Settings.settings` and instead trying to dereference a custom configuration section) not the act of deleting the config file.